# How to prevent the server from replying with 304?

Tags: http-status-code-304

I need to know the steps that I can do to prevent the server from replying with 304.

Comment: Can you be more precise? What server?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166433/how-to-prevent-request-that-returns-304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognized that It is not a good idea to do so.

However, If you need to do so, You can put some filter in the server to reset the value of `IF_MODIFIED_SINCE` request tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your client is probably sending an 'If-Modified-Since' header. Don't send it and you should be fine.

The intent of the header and the 304 reply is that if the client already has the latest data (as per the header 'If-Modified-Since'), there is no point in downloading it again.

Answer (score 1):

The server will send a 304 if the content has not been modified since a particular date. That date is set via the client's IF_MODIFIED_SINCE header. See [here](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E304.html) for more details.