# how to fix 304 - not modified error with wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I just freshly installed wordpress 4.8 and accessPress Parallax for theme (http://demo.accesspressthemes.com/accesspress-parallax/).

Now I see that, there's no parallax effect and responsive menu not working on mobile view. I suspect this has something to do with js files not loaded?

I checked the network tab and found many js files returning 304 error.
[image]

What does the 304 means here? How can I fix this? Currently I'm running on localhost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent request that returns 304](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166433/how-to-prevent-request-that-returns-304)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Status code `304` means that files was not modified since last load and browser can use it from local cache.

Answer (score 2):

Status code 304 means that files was not modified since last load and browser can use it from local cache.To make sure the browser loads data we need to edit the **.htaccess** file for apache servers. you can access it via filemanager from Control Pannel.

1. Take a backup of your htaccess file and website for safety
2. Make  sure to comment out or remove the contents of cache plugin (you may also see your old plugins data for me it was w3 total cache). just remove unnecessary cache data from .htaccess

```html
    # BEGIN WP Rocket v3.10.7
    # Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    # Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    .................
    </IfModule>
    # END WP Rocket
```

after removing it should be fine.

Comment: Please don't link to your own website when it's not strictly necessary. It makes the post look a lot like spam when you do that.